# Sql query to copy data and replace few entities while saving it again

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Please i need to copy data's from table and insert it again and only change the owner name and root name, i have bellow table structure for sample of what am trying to do. my coding is in php

It was saved in data base this way

```
id    | root | subname | type | owner
------|------|---------|------|----------
1     | AB   | subS0   | file | peter
2     | CB   | null    | txt  | peter  
3     | DF   | ast     | doc  | mike
4     | AB   | ghst    | cmd  | peter
5     | OF   | wmel    | inc  | john
```

Now i want to copy all data that the entity name is root and reinsert it with another entity name and owner name

After i have insert it will then look like this

```
id    | root | subname | type | owner
------|------|---------|------|----------
1     | AB   | subS0   | file | peter
2     | CB   | null    | txt  | peter  
3     | DF   | ast     | doc  | mike
4     | AB   | ghst    | cmd  | peter
5     | OF   | wmel    | inc  | john
6     | JK   | subS0   | file | james
7     | JK   | ghst    | cmd  | james
```

The above result copy all from table that the root name is `AB` and insert it with another root name `JK` and also change the owner name. 
Please how do i run sql query that will do this for me?

Here is sample code of what i tried to do

```
    <?php
    $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO filelist(name, owner, date, Description, PrivacyType, tags, Type)
    VALUES(:name, :owner, date, Description, PrivacyType, tags, :Type)
    SELECT name, owner, date, Description, PrivacyType, tags, Type 
//OR this way
    SELECT :name, :owner, date, Description, PrivacyType, tags, :Type 
    FROM filelist
    WHERE name = :copyfromHere
    ");
                $db->bind(':name', 'JK');
                $db->bind(':owner', 'james');
                $db->bind(':copyfromHere', 'AB');
                $db->bind(':Type', 'TT');
    ?>
```

Comment: your said logic isn't really very clear. Clarify more a bit

Comment: @Rahul i updated a sample query of what am trying to do

Comment: @Rahul please i need help, i know am getting close to the query but how to use it in pdo is my problem, is working when i run it in sql but when i implement it in my project is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with an alias:

Answer of your first Question:

```
INSERT INTO `filelist` (root, subname, type, owner)
SELECT 'JK', t.subname, t.type, 'James' FROM `filelist` as t WHERE t.root='AB'
```

And the same with your pdo-Example:

```
<?php
    $db->prepare("
    INSERT INTO filelist(name, owner, date, Description, PrivacyType, tags, Type)
    SELECT :name, :owner, t.date, t.Description, t.PrivacyType, t.tags, :Type 
     FROM filelist AS t
       WHERE t.name = :copyfromHere
");
            $db->bind(':name', 'JK');
            $db->bind(':owner', 'james');
            $db->bind(':copyfromHere', 'AB');
            $db->bind(':Type', 'TT');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the data you need as part of the sub-select in the insert

```
INSERT INTO filelist (root, subname, type, owner)
SELECT 'JK', subname, type, 'james' FROM filelist
```

using the constants inside the query is probably the easiest, if you want to control the values in PHP, replace with $variable.

Comment: in my case of sample query no need to add `VALUES(:root, :subname,: type, :owner)` again and am using php pdo in the select part will i do it this way `SELECT :JK, subname, type, :owner FROM filelist`? i just updated my question